# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que los WebView se muestren completo? Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

Tengo unos WebView en en unos fragmentos en una Tabbed Activity con Action Bar, pero no se muestran los archivos HTML locales completos en aplicación, quiero lograr que se pueda ver toda la información sin tener que ponerles dimensiones estáticas como 300dp, ya probé con Wrap Conten; Match Parent y Fill Parent, pero ninguna funciona.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo este código en el fragmento

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.facien.apliacionfacien.Finformatica2">

<ScrollView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/wView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

En el xml de la activity tengo este código.

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.facien.apliacionfacien.InformaticaActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Gracias.

Comment: Agrega el codigo del layout donde tienes el WebView.

Comment: Te refieres al código del FrameLayout donde está incluido el WebView?

Answer (score 0):

Google no recomienda el uso de `fill-parent`, en su lugar se utiliza `match-parent`.

Un `WebView` no necesita de un scroll como `ScrollView`, ya que el WebView posee su propio scroll.

Si solo tendrás el `WebView` en el layout, `RelativeLayout` es una mejor opción. Coloca el WebView dentro del RelativeLayout y utiliza el `match_parent` para hacer que el WebView sea del tamaño de la pantalla.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.facien.apliacionfacien.Finformatica2">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/wView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: No, sigue igual, al final tendré que poner las dimensiones estáticas el problema de eso es que puede quedar mal en dispositivos de tamaño distinto al mio.

Comment: pasame el link de una foto de como se ve.

Comment: https://ibb.co/g5nOkb
https://ibb.co/jtvLWG

En las dos el scroll ya está lo mas bajo posible, sin embargo no se puede ver el HTML completo.

Comment: Carga un link diferente en el webView, por ejemplo, el link de udemy https://www.udemy.com. Prueba y me dejas saber.

Comment: Igual, esta imagen es de la aplicación https://ibb.co/gAKKQb y esta otra abriendo el mismo link pero desde la aplicación de Chrome https://ibb.co/mty7BG , se ve que a la de la aplicación le falta una parte, las dos tienen el scroll lo mas bajo posible.

Comment: Yo veo el webView completo, no entiendo muy bien lo que quieres lograr y que es lo que falla.

Comment: ya vi cual es el problema tengo una propiedad en el Java del Activity que dice app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" y esto hace que el contenedor salga de la pantalla.

Comment: Ok, si eso soluciono tu problema, bien entonces.

Comment: Todavía no, estoy viendo como adaptar el contenedor a la pantalla, pero por lo menos ya se cual es el problema, muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Ya solucioné el problema, metí la `ToolBar` y el Contenenedor en un `LinearLayout` vertical así la propiedad :

`app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />`

tomó las características del Layout y no de la pantalla.